# Service not working?

Tags: android, xml, service, manifest, background-process

I am building a game where I want the user to go through many activities in 20 seconds. Once the 20 seconds is over, I want to send the user to the GameOver screen. To run the timer in the background, I used a service. The issue is, the service doesn't seem to be running?

[image]

The weird thing is, that even the toast isn't showing. Here is the place where I call the service:

[image]

Here is the manifest:

[image]

Please let me know as to why the service or the timer aren't running. Thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it! If you need any more code, just let me know and I will show you. Thanks!

:-)

```
{Rich}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services can't interact with UI, which is what `Toast` does. If you want to do that, try using `runOnUIThread` along with `getApplicationContext` or the fancy way with binding/callbacks. Also, take a look at `AlarmManager`, might be a simpler solution instead of running a service.

Comment: But I'm not interacting with UI, because technically i'm just calling another class.

Comment: If you take a look at `Toast.makeText(...)` you will see that you pass it a `Context` that in your case is a Service. That class interacts with UI using that context, which doesn't work properly if its a service.

Comment: What if I remove the toast, why doesn't GameOver get called?

Comment: Try adding a flag to your intent :`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` . I'm pretty sure its required if you aren't starting an `Activity` from inside another `Activity`.

Comment: I did that, but for some reason, it is still not working. Do you know any other things I can do that could make it work? I will make sure to mark you best answer and like your post once I get it! Thanks

Comment: You forgot to start the timer.

Comment: I have started the timer with cdt.start(); but it's still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93935/discussion-between-rich-and-jammaster).

Comment: Thanks, I marked you best answer and liked your post!

Answer (score 0):

`BroadcastReciever` should be a solution to get and to show the toasts. Just send the message from service and catch it in activity. Then use it wherever you want.

```
//Service class
final static String ACTION = "ACTION";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("StartToast", "Started!");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    return START_STICKY;
}

//Activity class
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceClass.class);

    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ServiceClass.ACTION);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public String startToast;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startToast = arg1.getStringExtra("StartedToast");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, startToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Once you register this receiver, you get the message and create a toast automatically when you send data with `intent.putExtra(....);` .